# Run Keras/Theano using GPU

Tags: python, keras, gpu, theano

I'm trying to run keras/theano using GPU on jupyter notebook, my system is mac os High Sierra 10.13 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M.

I followed instructions [on this site](https://blog.wenhaolee.com/run-keras-on-mac-os-with-gpu/): I installed cuda and cudnn, then edit `~/.bash_profile`. I can't use this command `$ THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN python imdb_cnn.py` since I'm using jupyter notebook.
Moreover I've also edit **.theanorc** file's and it looks like this:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu
force_device = True
optimizer_including=cudnn

[nvcc]
fastmath = True

[cuda]
root=Users/jack/cuda
```

Then, I tried to run this code to check if I was using Gpu:

```
from theano import function, config, shared, tensor
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], tensor.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, tensor.Elemwise) and
              ('Gpu' not in type(x.op).__name__)
              for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

...and I was using cpu instead!

What should I put on the top of this code to use GPU?
I've also tried to put this:

```
import os
os.environ['THEANO_FLAGS'] = "device=cuda,force_device=True,floatX=float32"
```

but it didn't work because I always get this output:

```
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float32, vector)>)] Looping 1000
times took 2.618842 seconds Result is [1.2317803 1.6187934 1.5227807
... 2.2077181 2.2996776 1.6232328] 
Used the cpu
```

---

**EDIT**: I try to run the previous "test" code on terminal using 
      `THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=cuda0,floatX=float32 python gpuocpu.py`

I get this error:

```
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jack/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 227, in <module>
    use(config.device)
  File "/Users/jack/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 214, in use
    init_dev(device, preallocate=preallocate)
  File "/Users/jack/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 99, in init_dev
    **args)
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 658, in pygpu.gpuarray.init
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 587, in pygpu.gpuarray.pygpu_init
```

I found [this thread](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/6006) and I run this on terminal: `set DEVICE=cuda0` and `set GPUARRAY_CUDA_VERSION=80` but I still get the same error plus the output saying that I'm using cpu.

---

***EDIT2***: I re-installed Cuda (using .dmg file, not from terminal), I followed [Invidia Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html) and applied this tips:

> 1. Uncheck System Preferences > Energy Saver > Automatic Graphic Switch
> 2. Drag the Computer sleep bar to Never in System Preferences > Energy Saver

Now i get this new error: `Segmentation fault: 11`

```
>>> import pygpu
>>> pygpu.test()
pygpu is installed in /Users/jack/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygpu
NumPy version 1.15.4
NumPy relaxed strides checking option: True
NumPy is installed in /Users/jack/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
Python version 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 14:01:38) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
nose version 1.3.7
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: I found out that, probably, there’s an issue with compatibility: Cuda 10.0 is not supported on NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M.

I should install Cuda 6.5 but I can’t install it since it’s not supported on Mac Os High Sierra 10.13.

There’s no way out.